# Async/Await code not being executes after await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have been going over async/await. I trying few simple examples but unable to understand flow of async and await . In below code

```js
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }, ms));
}

async function GetUser() {
  await wait(5000);
  console.log('world');
}

GetUser();
```

Why is the message "world" not logged? Only "Hello" prints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to resolve it. So call `r()`

```js
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Hello');
    r()
  }, ms));
}

async function GetUser() {
  await wait(3000)
  console.log('world');
}
GetUser()
```

Answer (score 5):

You should call the resolver.

```
function wait(ms) { 
 return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function(){console.log('Hello'); r();}, 
//                                                                   ^^^ this
ms));
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

- Here `wait()` method returns a Promise, the function of `await` keyword is to stop code execution until the returned Promise by `wait()` is resolved.
- So the code snippet in question, without using `async/await` will be as below. Note that the resolve function is not yet invoked here. Hence, once the snippet is executed only `Hello` will get printed in the console.

  ```js
      // First code snippet
      function wait(ms) {
          return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function () {
              console.log('Hello');
          }, ms));
      }

      function GetUser() {
          return wait(1000)
              .then(() => {
                  console.log("World")
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
              })
      }

      GetUser()
  ```
- Code snippet when `r()` is invoked. Here, once the snippet is executed `Hello` and `World` both are printed in the console.

  ```js
      // Second code snippet
      function wait(ms) {
          return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function () {
              console.log('Hello');
              r();
          }, ms));
      }

      function GetUser() {
          return wait(1000)
              .then(() => {
                  console.log("World")
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
              })
      }

      GetUser()
  ```
- The reason why the second code snippet works, has to do with how Promise is implemented in JS.

  - Handler function/functions attached to a promise with the help of `.then()` are invoked only when the promise is resolved.
  - Code snippet when `resolve` method is not invoked inside the executor function i.e, when the **Promise** is not resolved. Here, only code inside `setTimeout` is invoked and not the handlers.

    ```js
        function wait(ms) {
            return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('Hello');
            }, ms));
        }

        const promiseReturnedByWaitMethod = wait(2000);

        // Multiple handlers can be added to a promise reference, which are executed when the asynchronous operation is completed.

        // adding first handler
        promiseReturnedByWaitMethod.then(() => {
            console.log("First handler!!")
        });

        // adding second handler
        promiseReturnedByWaitMethod.then(() => {
            console.log("Second handler!!")
        });
    ```
  - Code snippet when `resolve` method is invoked inside the executor function i.e, when the **Promise** is resolved.

    ```js
        function wait(ms) {
              return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function () {
                  console.log('Hello');
                  r();
              }, ms));
          }

          const promiseReturnedByWaitMethod = wait(2000);

          // Multiple handlers can be added to a promise reference, which are executed when the asynchronous operation is completed.

          // adding first handler
          promiseReturnedByWaitMethod.then(() => {
              console.log("First handler!!")
          });

          // adding second handler
          promiseReturnedByWaitMethod.then(() => {
              console.log("Second handler!!")
          });
    ```