# console.log after await doesnt print its content

Tags: javascript, async-await

I read about async/await, but I've a question. I know that await only works with promises, but why in the code below, the last console doesn't print at all!

```
async function printMe() {
  console.log("First")
  await new Promise (resolve => {setTimeout(() => console.log("Async!!!"), 3000)})
  console.log("Last")
}

printMe()
```

Comment: Your promise is never fulfilled (`resolve` should be called) therfore awaiting it takes forever

Comment: You never call `resolve()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After an await call, it doesn't execute next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095697/after-an-await-call-it-doesnt-execute-next-line) or [Async/Await code not being executes after await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672231/async-await-code-not-being-executes-after-await)

Answer (score 2):

When using [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you need to call the `resolve` method to fulfil the promise:

```js
async function printMe() {
  console.log("First")
  await new Promise (resolve => {setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Async!!!")
    resolve()
  }, 3000)})
  console.log("Last")
}

printMe()
```

N.B: There is also a `reject` method available, you can find more about it by [reading the related MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)